# Keep link to /etc/alternatives/jre when switching java

Tags: java

I have 2 java on my server, where I installed java8 first, then java 11

by default, there is no jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre

```
[root@server-1:jvm]# ls -all
...
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 Mar 17 09:10 java -> /etc/alternatives/java_sdk
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  215 Mar 17 09:10 java-11-amazon-corretto
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   17 Mar 17 07:17 java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto.x86_64
```

While after I set the default java with alternative command, the link to /etc/alternatives/jre is created automatically

```
[root@server-1:jvm]# alternatives --config java
There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.
  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
 + 1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto.x86_64/jre/bin/java
*  2           /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 2

[root@server-1:jvm]# ls -all
...
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 Mar 17 09:10 java -> /etc/alternatives/java_sdk
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root  215 Mar 17 09:10 java-11-amazon-corretto
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   17 Mar 17 07:17 java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Mar 17 09:21 jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre  <<<<< i want to keep this
```

But once I switch back to java8, the jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre was removed.
How can I keep the link?

---

UPDATE: example problem what to be solved

A application have to access the cacert file in java, e.g.

```
***/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto.x86_64/jre***/lib/security/cacerts  
***/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64***/lib/security/cacerts
```

So I would like to have the /usr/lib/jvm/jre or /etc/alternatives/jre pointing to the java home

In case of corretto8

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto.x86_64/jre
```

In case of corretto11 (which the 'alternative' already did if I switch to )

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64
```

Comment: It sounds like, java 8 doesn't require that link. Why do you need it?

Comment: @matt for example an application on the server have to access the java's certificate files, if the server have the link, then even i switch the java between 8 and 11, the application will still work correctly as the link is pointing to the current java.

Comment: Maybe that is the actual question then. It sounds like, the package jre maintainers didn't feel that folder was necessary. Does java 8 work otherwise? Maybe create an example where the certificate is an issue when you switch jvm's.

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: Is this on Ubuntu? Also, did you consider using an env variable? I know some applications will use the $JAVA_HOME to find the JDK home. Also, if you're using a framework, like spring, you might tag that in your question to get a little more visibility.